# Can I store a PayPal account to be billed later without an authorization amount?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

My service's pricing is based on usage. There's no monthly/weekly subscription, it's one off charges for however much the service is used on that day.

If a user authorizes my service to charge X, but uses the service such that his bill is more than 15% or $75 more than X, I want to be able to charge the user's account appropriately.

PayPal seems to let me create an authorization for a set amount, but it won't process my payment if it's 15% or $75 more than the authorized amount. Is there an API that let's me authorize my service for charging the user's account without an amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a billing agreement through reference transactions. Reference Transactions makes a copy of an existing transaction and allows you to charge the customer a different amount. You have to be approved for Reference Transactions so Customer Support will need to put in a request to enable it on your PayPal Account. You can do a reference transaction off of an authorization of $1.00 or a sale. The below is the exact explanation from the PayPal Developer Site of Reference Transactions

> A **reference transaction** is a financial transaction from which
>   subsequent transactions can be derived. For example, a buyer purchases
>   an item on your site, and you use the PayPal transaction ID or
>   reference transaction ID later to initiate another transaction. A
>   reference transaction must have occurred within the past 730 days
>   because the ID may not be available after two years.

From the PayPal Developer Site: 
[Reference Transaction Information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/)
[How to Setup a Reference Transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/)
[How to Initiate a Reference Transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: Sweet. Just what I needed. Thank you!